# Rails active storage - Open/download link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

A question on `Active Storage`: I just updated to rails 5.2 and I am trying to open the attached document which is saved as a `blob`. Currently, it's redirecting to `root_path`, any idea how can I open/download it instead?

My code in Rails view is:

`<%= link_to(document.filename, rails_blob_path(document, disposition: "attachment")) %>`

Answer (score 47):

To Download:

```
<%= link_to document.filename, rails_blob_path(document, disposition: 'attachment') %>
```

To Preview:

```
<%= link_to document.filename, rails_blob_path(document, disposition: 'preview') %>
```

Source - [ActiveStorage#Linking to Files documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files)

Comment: i am facing NoMethodError: undefined method `rails_blob_path' for main:Object

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you.

```
<%= link_to 'download', rails_blob_path(document, disposition: "attachment") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, and if it helps others, I had to blob element in the path, so:

```ruby
link_to document.file.blob.filename, rails_blob_path(document.file.blob, disposition: 'preview')
```